# Помогите понять один нюанс связанный с DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Разбираясь с тем, что такое Dependency Injection (DI) я набрел на статью в WIKI [Внедрение зависимости](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Перевел приведенный там пример на C# и у меня получилаcь следующая реализация DI.

**Вопрос:** зачем в данной реализации присутствует класс `CarFactory`? Что это такое и зачем он нужен? Для чего используется?

**Интерфесы**

```
interface IEngine
{
    int getEngineRotation();
    void setFuelConsumptionRate(int FUEL_FLOW);
}

interface ICar
{
    int getSpeed();
    void setPedalPressure(int PEDAL_PRESSURE);
}
```

**Реализация**

```
class Engine : IEngine
    {
        int engineRotation = 0;

        public int getEngineRotation()
        {
            return engineRotation;
        }

        public void setFuelConsumptionRate(int FUEL_FLOW)
        {
            engineRotation = FUEL_FLOW;
        }
    }

class Car : ICar
{
    private IEngine _engine;

    public Car(IEngine engine)
    {
        _engine = engine;
    }

    public int getSpeed()
    {
        return _engine.getEngineRotation() * 10;
    }

    public void setPedalPressure(int PEDAL_PRESSURE)
    {
        _engine.setFuelConsumptionRate(PEDAL_PRESSURE * 2);
    }
}
```

**Использование**

```
class CarFactory
{
    public static ICar buildCar()
    {
        return new Car(new Engine());
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ICar newCar = CarFactory.buildCar();
        newCar.setPedalPressure(5);
        int speed = newCar.getSpeed();
        Console.WriteLine("Speed of the car is " + speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть так называемый шаблоны проектирования (design patterns), Фабрик - один из них. Суть вот в чём. Клиент хотит получить что-то, что делает то-то и то-то. Ему фиолетово кто делает то-то и то-то, главное чтобы делал. Он их не знает и в общем-то знать не хочет. Он знает фабрику, на которой работают человечки, которые делают то-тот и то-то. И он звонит на фабрику и просит отправить одного (не важно какого) человечка выполнить работу. На самом деле всё немножко сложней. Но думаю этого хватит для комментария.

Comment: Контейнер DI  является в общем случае фабрикой (фабрикой-посредником), в которой регистрируются человечки, умеющие делать то-то и то-то. И по запросу клиента он направляет их запросившему клиенту. Как если ты не умеешь сам починить кран, звонишь в ЖЭК и к тебе отпраляют либо пьяницу Иванова, либо бывшего программиста интеллигента Петрова, но тоже умеющего починить твой кран. Есть зависимость от ЖЭК, получи инъекцию (Иванов или Петров)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В контексте DI этот код демонстрирует выделение логики внедрения через конструктор (constructor injection) IEngine в Car в отдельном классе - фабрике.
Таким образом в основной программе можно использовать разные типы двигателя, не изменяя реализацию Car и Program, изменив лишь код CarFactory.

Гибкость этого подхода ограничена по сравнению с внедрением через конфигурируемый DI-контейнер, но имеет право на существование.

Comment: конфигурируемый DI-контейнер - это что? Можете дать ссылку на описание или название на английском?

Comment: DI (или IoC) контейнер - это класс, помогающий реализовать DI (или IoC) в проекте. Он содержит в себе логику, подобную (намного более сложную, разумеется) вашей CarFactory и предоставляет удобный интерфейс для осуществления операций, связанных с DI (или IoC).

Вот статья на хабре: http://habrahabr.ru/post/131993/

На самом деле всё очень просто, поэтому лучше сразу попробуйте использовать какой-нибудь контейнер (вот список: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)